# regular expression to remove a string conditionally

Tags: java, android, regex

I want to remove dd/ or /dd/ or /dd but then if it's /dd/ I want to replace it with / so that it looks like MM/YYYY.

```
dd/MM/YYYY
MM/dd/YYYY
MM/YYYY/dd


[^\p{Alpha}]*d+[^\p{Alpha}]*
```

The above is my current regex.

What I want to achieve is either,
MM/YYYY
YYYY/MM

Cause right now, if I replace /dd/, it results in

MMYYYY
or 
YYYYMM

Comment: Your question is a little bit vague. Do you want to remove /dd/ or replace it with something?

Answer (score 1):

The best one in terms of understandability is to spell out the three options as alternatives:

```
/dd(?=/)|^dd/|/dd$
```

That is:

- `/dd(?=/)` the string "/dd" anywhere in the text followed by (positive lookahead) a "/"
- or `^dd/` the string "dd/" at the beginning of the text
- or `/dd$` the string "/dd" at the end of the text

The first alternative is written with a lookahead for the ending slash after "/dd" so that this slash is not consumed, and left in the string so that "MM/dd/YYYY" keeps one slash in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking for are the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes in Java. Attempt to find a match for your regular expression, and for each match call the `replaceAll()` or `replaceOne()` function.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using the regex: `dd/|/dd`.

Not sure though by `d` you meant digits or just `d`. 
The regex you have there is more general and matches much more than required.

Comment: it would then ignore /dd/...it's a much bigger query.

Comment: It would not ignore `/dd/`. It will remove (replace with nothing) the first `dd/` and leave the first slash untouched. Of course this only works if by `d` and `M` and `Y` you do not mean any digit. If so, you need a more complex expression.